# jquery edit style attributes and values

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to edit style attributes of a div element:

here is my div element:

```
<div class="pp_content pre-scrollable" style="height: 206px; width: 544px;">
```

when I triger an event I want this element:

```
<div class="pp_content pre-scrollable" style="min-height: 206px; width: 544px;">
```

only height transformed to min-heigth with same values.

I need something like :`$(".pp_content.pre-scrollable").attr(??)`

How can I do this with jquery  ?

Comment: why not add the style to a class then toggle the class depending on need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*@KarthkeyanVedi* answer is close, here is how to do that but use the old value of `height` other than a static number:

```
var oldHeight = $(".pp_content.pre-scrollable").css('height');
$(".pp_content.pre-scrollable").css({ 'height' : '', 'min-height' : oldHeight });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using

`$(".pp_content.pre-scrollable").css({ 'height' : '', 'min-height' : '206px' });`

Comment: but 206 is not fix, how can I store that value to a local variable then use in this function as parameter ?

Comment: yes you can store value to a variable and use it, refer @SpencerWieczorek answer